# How to sort table by top header row only

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I know this question has been asked before but no solution satisfied me...

I want to place the column filtering inputs between the body and the column headers. I placed them in an extra `<tr>` inside `<thead>` (many sources say this works).

Everything works fine except that now it linked the sorting on these inputs instead of the headers. You can see an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/42wsa2cp/). 
I did not implement the column filtering in this example, but you can see that the sorting is now linked to the inputs instead of the first row in `<thead>`.

```
$(function() {
   var dataTable = $('#mainTable').DataTable({
       paging: false
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [orderCellsTop](http://datatables.net/reference/option/orderCellsTop) option set to `true` to use top row `<tr>` in `<thead>` for sorting. From the manual:

> Allows control over whether DataTables should use the top (`true`) unique cell that is found for a single column, or the bottom (`false` - default) to attach the default order listener. This is useful when using complex headers.

```
var dataTable = $('#mainTable').DataTable({
   paging: false,
   orderCellsTop: true
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42wsa2cp/1/) for demonstration.