# How can I prevent ordering by click on column names but It should work when I click on the sort icon in the DataTable function?

Tags: python, flask, datatables

Heii guys, hope you are all fine!

I used Flask in python to create a table and used the function DataTable.
The problem is I have a sort icon (which is is included in DataTable) and I created search field s under the column names but when I'm clicking on the search field the column is getting sorted but I want to avoid this. I want that the column just get sorted when I click on the sort icon.

[And here is a part of the html code where Im using the DataTable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mYJo.png)[Here is a part of the flask table, to see what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6SNL.png)

I tried table.order.listener but didn't work and also disabling icon function but that's not what I want. I wanted to know if it is even possible to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort table by top header row only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317149/how-to-sort-table-by-top-header-row-only)

Comment: [Please don't use images for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: There is also an official DataTables example using `orderCellsTop: true` - see [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html). You can ignore the use of `fixedHeader: true` - that is not relevant to your problem.